# Node: Knex postgres query doesn't trigger unless 'then' is appended

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm using Node with postgresql. I'm trying to do a knex query to the bd.

Why this query doesn't work without the then() call?

```
knex('test').insert(User1).then();
```

Comment: Just a note, if you are using async/await you can await it: `await knex('test')...` and it will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

it's because the framework expects you to either fulfill the promise or to invoke any other provided [output interfaces](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces)

to chain the promise output is one of the cleaner ways to end the query building step, see this little [example](https://github.com/sombriks/blogpost-vue-browserify-bookshelf/blob/master/evento-servico/lib/participante.js#L16), hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's expected behavior.